# Any way to call Controller from Route::inertia() facade?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, routes, inertiajs

I can serve pages with `inertia` like so:

```
Route::inertia('/home', 'home');
```

To load a page with data from a database, I have to do this:

```
Route::get('/terms', [LegalPageController::class, 'index']);
```

and in the controller:

```
class LegalPageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $record = Terms::first();

        return inertia('terms', compact('record'));
    }
}
```

Is there any way to shorten this into something like:

```
Route::inertia('/home', 'home', [Controller::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do

```php
Route::inertia('/home', 'home', [Controller::class, 'index']);
```

instead use this method

```php
#routes/web.php
Route::get('home', [Controller::class, 'index']);


#App\Http\COntrollers\Controller.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers

class Controller extends Controller {
    # ...
   Inertia::render('home');
}
```